# amCharts (V4): first month format in DateAxis without year

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

In a **XYChart** I am trying to set on the x-Axes, the twelve months as lables, from Jan to Dec, but as shown in the picture, the first month has also the *Year (yyyy)*.

```
let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
```

How can I show just the name of the month, in this case, just "*Jan*" ?

[image: DateAxis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `dateFormats.setKey` and `periodChangeDateFormats.setKey` to format the dates on a date axis; see [this tuto](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Formatting_date_and_time).

Here the smoking gun is `periodChangeDateFormats`. This option controls the formatting when a period changes (e.g. a new year when the scale is month). I have not tried but I think you need:

```
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("month", "MMM"); // useless, this is the default
dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("month", "MMM");
```

while the default is `dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("month", "MMM yyyy")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply [disable marking the unit changes](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#markUnitChange_adapter) with `dateAxis.markUnitChange = false`.

This property is used to apply the different formats defined in `periodChangeDateFormats` to the first label in bigger time unit, i.e.

- when the resolution is monthly and a new year starts
- when the resolution is weekly and a new months starts
- when the resolution is hourly and a new day starts
- etc.

*(There is an exception for the daily resolution, where the period changes with the next months and not with the next week.)*